# Can Body Double copy the back face of a card in the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

Just wondering, if the [Ludevic's Test Subject](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLudevic%27s%5d%2b%5bTest%5d%2b%5bSubject%5d) is in the grave, can [Body Double](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBody%20Double%5d) enter play copying the Abomination side?

Answer (score 9):

No, it cannot. [Rule 711.4a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Double-faced_cards) says

> While a double-faced card is outside the game, in a zone other than the battlefield, or on the battlefield with its front face up, it has only the characteristics of its front face.

Comment: Thought I had a cool combo going... oh well. Thanks for clarifying.